# Get url parameters in NancyFx

Tags: nancy

I am using NancyFx to build a web API, but I am facing some problems when getting parameters from the URL.

I need to send, to the API, the request `.../consumptions/hourly?from=1402012800000&tags=%171,1342%5D&to=1402099199000` and catch the value of the parameters: granularity, from, tags and to. I tried several approches and none worked. I tried, for example,

```
Get["consumptions/{granularity}?from={from}&tags={tags}&to={to}"] = x =>
{
    ...
}
```

How can I do this?

Luis Santos

Answer (score 79):

There are 2 things that you are trying to get from the URL. One is a part of the path `hourly` - and the other is the parameters in the query string - namely the values for `from` and `to`.

You can get to the part of the path through the parameter to the handler - the `x` in your example.

You can get to the query string through the `Request` which is accessible on the `NancyModule`.

To put this in code:

```
Get["consumptions/{granularity}"] = x =>
{
    var granularity = x.granularity;
    var from = this.Request.Query["from"];
    var to = this.Request.Query["to"];
}
```

The variables `granularity`. `from`, and `to` are all `dynamic`, and you may need to convert them to whatever type you want.

Answer (score 17):

You can let NancyFx's model binding take care of the url query string.

```
public class RequestObject 
{
    public string Granularity { get; set; }
    public long From { get; set; }
    public long To { get; set; }
}
```

/consumptions/hourly?from=1402012800000&to=1402099199000

```
Get["consumptions/{granularity}"] = x =>
{
    var request = this.Bind<RequestObject>();
}
```

Comment: this can be a nice solution if your input data is a lot to parse, but is usually unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
var from = Request.Query.from;
```